# gsd-color color transform matrix permission denied

Tags: permissions, monitors, gsettings

I am investigating a monitor wakeup problem and one of the errors noted by journalctl is:

```
Jan 03 14:24:11 konradsdesktop gsd-color[1238]: failed to set xrandr-Samsung Electric Company-LC32G7xT-H4ZNC00839 color transform matrix: failed to load file: Error opening file /var/lib/gdm/.local/share/icc/edid-0cf076c6b85cdbfbf9cb9297df735a8b.icc: Permission denied
```

But the file is readable for the gdm user:

```
$ sudo ls -lah /var/lib/gdm/.local/share/icc/edid-0cf076c6b85cdbfbf9cb9297df735a8b.icc
-rw-r--r-- 1 gdm gdm 1.6K Jun 28  2021 /var/lib/gdm/.local/share/icc/edid-0cf076c6b85cdbfbf9cb9297df735a8b.icc
```

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

### Versions

- GNOME Shell 41.2
- Arch Linux with Kernel 5.12.18-1-ck-skylake
- gsettings 2.70.2

### Detailed Log

```
Jan 03 14:15:06 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[11088]: console.error: Calendar:
Jan 03 14:15:06 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[11088]:   Couldn't find Amsterdam, Belgrade, Berlin, Brussels, Budapest, Madrid, Paris, Prague, Stockholm
Jan 03 14:15:07 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[11164]: JavaScript error: moz-extension://6b7b9df9-493d-4102-928c-59bc60e81436/ad.js, line 732: TypeError: this.compose_window.canSpellCheck is not a function
Jan 03 14:15:08 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[11088]: insertDefaultTemplate
Jan 03 14:15:40 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[11088]: console.log: "CURSOR LOG failedSearchAttempts : 1"
Jan 03 14:16:49 konradsdesktop gnome-shell[1139]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55b503cde370] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 03 14:16:49 konradsdesktop gnome-shell[1139]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55b503e5c340] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 03 14:16:49 konradsdesktop gnome-shell[1139]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55b5043fea40] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 03 14:16:55 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (EE) event18 - HID 046a:0011: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 33ms, your system is too slow
Jan 03 14:17:34 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (EE) event18 - HID 046a:0011: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 26ms, your system is too slow
Jan 03 14:17:48 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (EE) event18 - HID 046a:0011: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 20ms, your system is too slow
Jan 03 14:19:08 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (EE) event18 - HID 046a:0011: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 17ms, your system is too slow
Jan 03 14:19:08 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (EE) event18 - HID 046a:0011: WARNING: log rate limit exceeded (5 msgs per 60min). Discarding future messages.
Jan 03 14:19:29 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[11088]: ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
Jan 03 14:23:53 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG Ultra HD (DFP-0): connected
Jan 03 14:23:53 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG Ultra HD (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jan 03 14:23:53 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG Ultra HD (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 03 14:23:53 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 03 14:23:53 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG Ultra HD (DFP-0): connected
Jan 03 14:23:53 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG Ultra HD (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Jan 03 14:23:53 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG Ultra HD (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jan 03 14:23:53 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (**) Option "fd" "36"
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (**) Option "fd" "39"
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (**) Option "fd" "40"
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) event20 - Razer Razer DeathAdder: device removed
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (**) Option "fd" "41"
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) event18 - HID 046a:0011: device removed
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (**) Option "fd" "42"
Jan 03 14:24:04 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) event19 - Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000: Mi: device removed
Jan 03 14:24:05 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Jan 03 14:24:05 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:82
Jan 03 14:24:05 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:84
Jan 03 14:24:05 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:83
Jan 03 14:24:05 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Jan 03 14:24:05 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: [GFX1-]: GFX: RenderThread detected a device reset in PostUpdate
Jan 03 14:24:07 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: Unflushed glGetGraphicsResetStatus: 0x92bb
Jan 03 14:24:11 konradsdesktop gsd-color[1238]: failed to set xrandr-Samsung Electric Company-LC32G7xT-H4ZNC00839 color transform matrix: failed to load file: Error opening file /var/lib/gdm/.local/share/icc/edid-0cf076c6b85cdbfbf9cb9297df735a8b.icc: Permission denied
Jan 03 14:24:11 konradsdesktop gsd-color[1238]: failed to set xrandr-Samsung Electric Company-LC32G7xT-H4ZNC00839 color transform matrix: failed to load file: Error opening file /var/lib/gdm/.local/share/icc/edid-0cf076c6b85cdbfbf9cb9297df735a8b.icc: Permission denied
Jan 03 14:24:14 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
Jan 03 14:24:14 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:82
Jan 03 14:24:14 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:84
Jan 03 14:24:14 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:83
Jan 03 14:24:14 konradsdesktop /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[1091]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:65
Jan 03 14:24:14 konradsdesktop gsd-color[1238]: failed to set xrandr-Samsung Electric Company-LC32G7xT-H4ZNC00839 color transform matrix: failed to load file: Error opening file /var/lib/gdm/.local/share/icc/edid-0cf076c6b85cdbfbf9cb9297df735a8b.icc: Permission denied
Jan 03 14:24:20 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: [GFX1]: Device reset due to WR context
Jan 03 14:24:20 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: [GFX1-]: GFX: RenderThread detected a device reset in PostUpdate
Jan 03 14:24:20 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: Unflushed glGetGraphicsResetStatus: 0x92bb
Jan 03 14:24:20 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: Unflushed glGetGraphicsResetStatus: 0x92bb
Jan 03 14:24:24 konradsdesktop gsd-color[1238]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Samsung_Electric_Company_LC32G7xT_H4ZNC00839_gdm_120
Jan 03 14:24:33 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: [GFX1]: Device reset due to WR context
Jan 03 14:24:33 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: [GFX1-]: GFX: RenderThread detected a device reset in PostUpdate
Jan 03 14:24:33 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: Unflushed glGetGraphicsResetStatus: 0x92bb
Jan 03 14:24:33 konradsdesktop gsd-media-keys[6239]: Unflushed glGetGraphicsResetStatus: 0x92bb
```

### Update

The problem still persists as of 2022-04-27, however I also noticed those errors:

```
[...] gnome-shell[17157]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55bc2b716360] is on because it needs an allocation.
[...] gnome-shell[17157]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55bc2c207300] is on because it needs an allocation.
[...] gnome-shell[17157]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55bc2ca19820] is on because it needs an allocation.
```

Comment: I get the same issue, have you been able to fix it yet?

Comment: @Climax: The problem still persists and I still get the message, however I'm not sure if that is the culprit because I just had a wakeup problem where the message didn't occur at that time but only on boot.